# Reading text file to string without huge memory consumption

Tags: java, file-io, memory-leaks, nio

I've tried to measure performance of several approaches to read a file into string using NIO (slowest for reading single file), BufferedInputStream and reading the file line after line (600 ms average per pass) and then this stream using Filereader and an array with fixed size acting as a buffer (fastest)

File was 95 MB of pure text in windows .txt file format. Converting chars to string really is the bottleneck, but what I noticed is HUGE memory consumption of this method. For 95 MB of lorem ipsum, this consumes up to 1 GB of RAM. I haven't found why.

What I have tried with no effect:

Issuing Garbage Collector by calling System.gc()
Setting all the pointer variables to null before method ends (but they should be anyway, they are defined only within method).

```
private void testCharStream() {
            File f = f = new File("c:/Downloads/test.txt");
    long oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    char[] cbuf = new char[8192];
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);

        while (reader.read(cbuf) != -1) {
            builder.append(cbuf);
        }

        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(currentTime - oldTime);
}
```

Comment: Why read a file that big into a string at all? Why not process it line by line?

Comment: System.gc() is a request, not an order. Setting variables to null does absolutely nothing the vast majority of the time. ==EJP

Comment: I have files of data in old format with size varying between 4 MB to 50 MB. I wrote a program to convert them to a new format being currently used and the process took one hell of a time. I need to have whole file in memory in order to run regexp properly. I was really expecting better results, so I tried to find the bottleneck.

Comment: use Scanner class to read the file line by line which won't keep anything in memory, you can read file size over your RAM size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Apache Commons IO: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/
I didn't benchmark it but I think the code is optimised.

Comment: I will definitely give it a try and post the results. Thank you.

Comment: Apache commons IO library is definitely memory-optimized. While reading the 95 MB of text mentioned in my question, highest memory usage was 777,1 MB exactly, which is over 300 MB less than method in my question. But it was dropping down to 220 MB time after time while repeating the reading operation 200 times in a row. But it was slightly slower, over 710 ms average per pass against 492 ms average achieved with my method.

Comment: use Scanner class to read the file line by line which won't keep anything in memory, you can read file size over your RAM size

Answer (score 0):

I came up with decent solution. Using Apache Commons IO Package, memory peak was **777,1 MB**, lowest 220 MB and 710 ms average needed for the 95 MB text file to be red.

What I did was to set variable with pointer to StringBuilder object to null at the end of method and suggested garbage colletor to actually do it's work (System.gc()). Memory peak is **540 MB**, more than 1/2 of value previously achieved ! Also by changing buffer size to 1024 means  40 ms improvement per pass, from 490 to 450 or even less. So my function needs only **63.4 %** of the Apache's time to read the file. That's almost **40 %** less. Any ideas how to get the performance improved even more ?

Here is the function.

```
private void testCharStream() {
    long oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);

        while (reader.read(cbuf) != -1) {
            builder.append(cbuf);
        }

        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    builder = null;
    System.gc();
    System.out.println(currentTime - oldTime);
}
```

Comment: `Any ideas how to get the performance improved even more ?` - one idea - don't read the file. Really. It will be slow, no matter what you do.

Comment: Your read code is wrong. It should be 'while ((count = reader.read(cbuf)) > 0) { builder.append(cbuf, 0, count); }'. Otherwise you are dealing in junk at least at the end of the file, possibly elsewhere too.

Comment: use Scanner class to read the file line by line which won't keep anything in memory, you can read file size over your RAM size

Answer (score 0):

To get better performance you can use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). This class allows you to read the file line by line. Rather than wasting time by reading the file word by word this method will perform the task much faster. You can read a file of plain text (Size: 1 MB) in half second. Just use the following code.

> File f=new File("File path"); 
>   FileReader fr=new FileReader(f) 
>   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr); 
>  
>   String line=""; 
>   StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(); 
>   try { 
>   while((line=br.readLine())!=null) 
>   builder.append(line+"\n"); 
>   }
>   catch(Exception e) 
>   { 
> e.printStackTrace();
>  }

You can check the time it takes to read the file as you've used the `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: Actually this one is the second slowest after using NIO. My solution with EJP's "junk fix" costs is two times faster. BufferedReader alone may be as fast (but not faster, many times slower), but creating those string and pushing them into StringBuilder is the real bottleneck. This makes it very slow (450 ms vs 870 ms per 95 MB). Actually my solution reads 95 MB of various text in under half a second. 1 MB file should be done in few milliseconds. But often this is done in one millisecond on my notebook. But thank you for your effort.

Comment: use Scanner class to read the file line by line which won't keep anything in memory, you can read file size over your RAM size